# Issues accessing file shares on a single Win 10 PC

Tags: windows-10, file-permissions

So I have a windows 10 device on a domain that is giving me "Permission" issues when attempting to access network drives that are mapped through our GPOs.

This issue occurs with any domain account you sign in with. The mapped drives do appear but then when accessing you get the "Permissions" errors as stated.

What I have found out is the following:

1. accessing through hostname brings up the same issues. EX: \serverName\Share
2. Accessing through IP doesn't bring up any errors and lets me access as normal. EX: \X.X.X.X\Share
3. Accessing through the FQDN also works and allows access as normal. EX: \serverName.domain.local\Share

I've tried resetting CSC already as read in other forum posts but that has not assisted. The machine has been fully wiped and removed from domain / rejoined.

Not sure what else at this point so any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Use the NET USE approach and then please let us know what numerical error you get.

Comment: @John, When I do the NET USE approach I am prompted for a username and PW although I am already logged in as the domain user.

When I input the login credentials it gives me an access denied error again pointing to "permissions errors", but when I use NET USE A: \\serverName.domain.local\Share it doesn't do the same issue and maps the network drive just fine making it accessible.

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: if you use your name and password, do you get a folder connection?  Does that work?

Comment: It doesn't. Just displays access denied and no network drive is mapped. If I do it using the FQDN then all works just fine.

Comment: In Advanced Network and Sharing Center, do you have Network Discovery and File/Print Sharing both enabled? Have you got Password Protected Sharing ON and 128-bit encryption enabled?

Comment: Yes, I do. I also turned off firewall to test and none of that has gotten access to any of the mapped network drives.

Comment: I am not sure. You wiped and reinstalled this machine. One machine only. It would appear something went wrong with the install. I cannot think of any other setting that would case this

Comment: Thank you for helping! I'll keep looking into this.

Comment: Figured it out! Looks like this computer was updated to windows version 2004 recently. This can be considered a bug.